# WP_Query, using AND with OR

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below PHP:-

```
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_type'     => 'jobs',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        's' => $search_field,
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_salary_from',
                'value'     => $job_salary_from,
                'compare'   => '>=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_salary_from',
                'value'     => $job_salary_to,
                'compare'   => '<=',
            ),
            array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_salary_to',
                'value'     => $job_salary_from,
                'compare'   => '>=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_salary_to',
                'value'     => $job_salary_to, 
                'compare'   => '<=',
            ),
        ))              
    );
```

Lets say there is a job that is from 19000 to 22000 called 'ABC', so
`job_salary_from` = 19000
and `job_salary_to` = 22000.

Now lets say I search a job that is between 10000 and 19000, so `$job_salary_from` = 10000 and `$job_salary_to` = 19999.

This shows up when I do a search which is correct. However, if I search for a job that is between 20000 and 29999, so `$job_salary_from` = 19999 and `$job_salary_to` = 29999 nothing is showing up.

Where as the job 'ABC' should show up because `$job_salary_to` is within the search bracket.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the meta_query syntax is not quite right. Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'post_type'     => 'jobs',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    's' => $search_field,
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',

        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_salary_to',
                'value'     => $job_salary_from,
                'type'    => 'numeric', //for each case
                'compare'   => '>=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_salary_to',
                'value'     => $job_salary_to,
                'type'    => 'numeric',
                'compare'   => '<=',
            ),
        ),

        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_salary_from',
                'value'     => $job_salary_from,
                'type'    => 'numeric',
                'compare'   => '>=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'job_salary_from',
                'value'     => $job_salary_to,
                'type'    => 'numeric',
                'compare'   => '<=',
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

Also you can try to use `BETWEEN`, even I am not sure if this is inclusive or exclusive compare.

Comment: Yep it was the syntax of the query, combined this with using BETWEEN like @Saurabh Srb solution and it's all working as expected :)

Comment: You're welcome, but as I sad, you must check if `BETWEEN` will do exactly the same job for the limit cases. Maybe you must add or substract 1 to make query the same as above one :)

Answer (score 1):

that is because there is a different function to fetch results in between a range.

Try the following example to fetch results in between a range

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'color',
            'value'   => 'blue',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value'   => array( 20, 100 ),
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

More resources here https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query